# rails, rewrite a route based on user's ip address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a search indexer indexing specific pages within my application.  The urls we build for indexing are aggregates of content that are served within other pages in the application.  The indexer should see the aggregate page, the user should see the first page/dashboard of the found topic.

I'd like to see how i can route (via routes.rb or before_filter) everyone except the search indexer to the topic's dashboard.

For example.  the aggregate page is here /topics/123-my-topic/searchindex.  The indexer returns that page as relevant content as it has all of topic 123's content.  when a user (not search indexer ip) goes to /topics/123-my-topic/searchindex, they should be routed to /topics/123-my-topic.

Essentially, what's the best way to strip /searchindex off the request for everyone but a known IP address?

This can probably be accomplished with .htaccess in apache, but i'd prefer to keep this within my application so I dont have to modify files on the servers if the indexer ip address ever changes.

Thank you

Matt

Answer (score 0):

```
before_filter :redirect_users

def searchindex
  # :id => '123-my-topic'
  redirect_users
  # Handle searchindex traffic for the indexer
end

def redirect_users
  unless ip == '127.0.0.1'
    redirect_to :action => :show, :id => :topic_id
  end
end
```

Comment: so i'm clear, can i place this into my topics controller to just run against topics requests?  also can this work for any topics requested /topics/123-topic1/searchindex => /topics/123-topic1, /topics/124-topic2/searchindex => /topics/124-topic2   etc...  newbie to rails here, thank you.

Comment: You should put this in your TopicsController. All the redirect_users method does is figure out if it's the indexer or not. If it's not it redirects them to the show action instead of the searchindex action.